# running command line args in C#

Tags: c#, windows, process, cmd, command

I'm just switching over to C# from Java, so bear with me. From what I've read in several places online, you need to run commands with the following syntax:

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe","/C <<command>>");
```

But, when I do that, the command window opens and immediately closes.

So, I try it without the /C for kicks.

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe","<<command>>");
```

This time, the command window stays open, but nothing happens -- no command is run. I've tried it with even the simplest commands.

What am I doing wrong? I'm sure it's a noobish mistake.

Thank you in advance. Using Visual C# 2010 Express.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `/K`

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/k dir c:\\");
```

Note that running `cmd.exe dir c:\` from the shell would not work either as the command line is not valid without a leading `/K` or `/C` switch.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! So, what's the difference between /K and /C? When should I use one as opposed to the other?

Comment: `cmd.exe /?` == `/C` runs the command and terminates, `/K` runs the command keeping the cmd process alive and active when finished.